# Can we change the text of the generic NaA comment in the Low Quality Posts review?

Tags: discussion, comments, review-queue

The text, as it stands, is as follows:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

This looks like something that was copied in from SO. The issue I have with it is whenever I use it, I have to remove the entire last half as it is basically never applicable.

It ends up looking like this:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

I understand sometimes we have answers that necessitate the current comment, but by and large, SFF questions spawn answers that are comments acting as "answers", not comments acting as questions. As has been mentioned elsewhere, random comments posted as answers don't necessarily need an auto comment. However, given the title in the popup (see below), I feel this is misleading to anyone who is unfamiliar with the system (and even for those who are).

I recommend changing the text to my truncated version, or replacing the removed portion with text more appropriate to the type of comment-answers we see on SFF.

---

[image]

Comment: Mods can't make a change like this. CMs may be able to, but in order for them to do that, you'd have to either a) make a good case for why SFF in particular really needs this auto-comment changed or b) get enough support on main meta for a network-wide change. The latter is *extremely* unlikely, IMO; I don't know about the former, since I personally can't see a reason to change this.

Comment: I stick to my own set of canned responses and use them with the help of [autoreviewcomments](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/37743) userscript.